# Dynamic Programming problem - extending to find all possible paths to sum

Tags: go, dynamic-programming

I'm doing a [DP course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk) to brush up (it's great and has helped me a ton), and one of the problems is `given a target sum and a list of numbers, is there a path to the target / what is the best (shortest) path?`

I've solved the `pathExists` and `bestPath`  problems, but was stuck thinking about a problem they didn't ask the solution to - can you list ALL paths to the solution:

golang code below for best

golang

```
func BestSum(ts int, nums []int) []int {
    var best []int
    return bs(ts, nums, best)
}

func bs(ts int, nums, best []int) []int {
    if ts == 0 {
        return []int{}
    } else if ts < 0 {
        return nil
    }

    for _, n := range nums {
        rc := bs(ts-n, nums, best)
        if rc != nil {
            path := append(rc, n)
            if best == nil || len(best) > len(path){
                best = path
            }           
        }
    }

    return best
}
```

// example would be:
BestSum(7, [5,3,4,7]) // ans: [7]

Since we cover all paths here anyway, I wanted to see if I could return all paths, but am getting stuck on a piece of the logic:

```
func AllSum(ts int, nums []int) [][]int {
    all := [][]int{}

    var as func(int, []int) []int 
    as = func(s int, nums []int) []int {
        if s == 0 {
            return []int{}
        } else if s < 0 {
            return nil
        }
    
        var path []int
        for _, n := range nums {
            rc := as(s-n, nums)
            if rc != nil {
                path = append(rc, n)
// this section iterates over path so far each time (slow) and sums to see if it can append yet
                var sum int
                for _, c := range path {
                    sum+=c
                }
                if sum == ts {
                    all = append(all, path)
                }
            }
        }
    
        return path
    }

    _ = as(ts, nums)
    return all
}
```

The above code passes for `7, [5,4,3,7]` but fails for `20, [2,10]` missing `[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]`

Is there a well known pattern for collecting all paths from a function generating paths recursively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI the above solution posted was giving incorrect answers, and the DP course actually went on to explain the solution to a similar problem that allowed me to figure out the solution to this one:

```
func AllSum(ts int, nums []int) [][]int {
    return as(ts, nums)
} 

func as(s int, nums []int) [][]int {
    if s == 0 {
        return [][]int{{}}
    }
    
    var all [][]int
    for _, n := range nums {
        if s-n < 0{
            continue
        }

        paths := as(s-n, nums)
        for i, _ := range paths {
            paths[i] = append(paths[i], n)
            all = append(all, paths[i])
        }
    }

    return all
}
```

Linked to fixed code: https://play.golang.org/p/cpEKgV2e1kM

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current algorithm is that the recursive function can only return one possible solution; for example when it reaches `12, [2 2 2 2]` there is more than one solution (including `[2 2 2 2 10 2]` and `[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]`) but you will only return one (you check all paths but many of the results are thrown away).

A common solution is to pass the path into the recursive function; e.g:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(AllSum(20, []int{2, 10}))
    fmt.Println(AllSum(7, []int{5,4,3,7}))
}

func AllSum(ts int, nums []int) [][]int {
    return allSum(ts, nums, nil)
}

func allSum(s int, nums []int, path []int) [][]int {
    if s < 0 {
        return nil // No solution here
    }
    if s == 0 { // solution found
        return [][]int{path}
    }
    
    // Copy the path to avoid editing other solutions
    p := make([]int, len(path))
    copy(p, path)
    
    var solutions [][]int
    for _, n := range nums {
        rc := allSum(s-n, nums, append(p, n))
        if rc != nil {
            solutions = append(solutions, rc...)
        }
    }
    return solutions
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Xn5CUqTR-lv)